# Nivo Slider just doesn't show up? All code seems good

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I've added Nivo Slider to a wordpress home page. I've used it before, and I've followed the steps exactly, but the slideshow does not show up at all. If you view the source of the page you can see the code surrounded by "Nivo Slider" comments. If I take the script that fires the slider completely out, the images appear, but with the script included the slider vanishes. I hope someone with fresh eyes can spot what I'm overlooking. Here is the link:
http://phillipsandphillipslaw.com/

Edit: I found that the height setting of "auto" was preventing the slideshow from showing up, so I set it to the height of the images, and it appears, but it still isn't working. So it seems that something it breaking but I can't determine what it is. I don't get any errors in the console, so I'm stuck in the diagnosis.

It must be a conflict - but I'm not sure how to rule that out.

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body  : $('#slider-wm').nivoSlider();` not sure if it helps but fix it and see?

Comment: Good catch but didn't seem to fix it. I also noticed that the Wordpress Toolbar does not show up on the live site while logged in, so that is likely related, but I don't know how on earth to diagnose where the bug is.

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list : };`   your code should be  `$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider-wm').nivoSlider();
});`

Comment: Thank you for spotting that as well, unfortunately it did not solve it yet.

Comment: I should say that the syntax error did fix the toolbar.

Comment: `TypeError: $ is not a function : $('#slider-wm').nivoSlider();` you could use jQuery.noConflict or change that line to `jQuery('#slider-wm').nivoSlider();`

Comment: Well done! Fixed! That fixed the conflict. Thanks so much! Owe you a beer!